# tableview internal inconsistency when deleting

Tags: uitableview, ios6

I have an array (datasource) with a set of addresses, my tableview is set to have double the amount of cells from the datasource so I can style the odd cells to be small and clear (to make the tableview look like the cells are separated by a small space). My problem comes when deleting a row, I do the following:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[tableView beginUpdates];
if (editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self DeleteAddress:[ListAddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row/2]];

        [ListAddress removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row/2];
        NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:indexPath.row+1];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath,nextIndexPath,nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    }else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert){
         [self tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }
[tableView endUpdates];
}
```

The DeleteAddress method deletes the address from the database.
When the debugger reaches the [tableview endUpdate] function a get the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070
NSInternalInconsistencyException
```

Comment: There should be a lot more to the error you are getting. Most likely the problem is that your code deletes two rows from the table (indexPath and nextIndexPath) but you don't delete two rows from your data source or you delete the wrong rows from the data source. Also, you should only put the `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` calls around the "delete" code since the "insert" code doesn't do anything.

Comment: My datasource doesn't have values for odd rows because I created them just for aesthetic purposes, so I delete only row from the datasource but delete 2 visual rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was creating my nextIndexPath variable the wrong way. It should have been like this:

```
NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
```

Also I couldn't delete both rows at the same time, I needed to delete them separately from bottom:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the sample code.Delete one row from your data source.Hope its useful for you.This code works for my app.Try it

```
//  Swipe to delete has been used.  Remove the table item

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //  Get a reference to the table item in our data array
        Pictures *itemToDelete = [self.pictureListData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //  Delete the item in Core Data
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:itemToDelete];

        //  Remove the item from our array
        [pictureListData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //  Commit the deletion in core data
        NSError *error;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
            NSLog(@"Failed to delete picture item with error: %@", [error domain]);

        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
}
```